# How higher order function works in scala?

Tags: scala

I am working with higher order function but I am confused how it works.

```
def normal(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int):Int=a+b+c
```

When I call `normal(1,2,3)` this return 6 as we did `= a+b+c`. But in higher order

```
def higher_order(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int,f:(Int,Int)=>Int):Int=f(f(a,b),c)
```

When I call `higher_order(1,2,3,_+_)` it also returns 6 but how? Where does this function do the addition?

Comment: The addition is done here: `_+_` Try some different operations and see what happens. `higher_order(2,3,5,_*_)` or `higher_order(21,2,3,_-_)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I call higher_order(1,2,3,*+*) it also returns 6 but how? Where does this function do the addition?

Lets go step by step:

```scala
higher_order(1, 2, 3, _ + _) // Original line.
higher_order(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, f = (x, y) => x + y) // Sugar syntax.
f(f(1, 2), 3) // By definition of higher_order.
f((1 + 2), 3) // By the definition of the inner f.
(1 + 2) +  3 // By the definition of the external f.
6 // By evaluation of +.
```

Hope this helps you understand what is happening.
Feel free to ask any questions.