# How are Function Values processed in Higher Order Methods without definition in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to understand how without defining the function variables methods still work.
Code in case:

```
@ class Box(var x: Int) {
  def update(f: Int => Int) = x = f(x)
  def printMsg(msg: String) = {
    println(msg + x)
```

Now, if I perform the following calls, I get the desired output:

```
val b = new Box(1)
b.printMsg("Hello")
```

> Hello1

```
b.update(i => i + 5)
b.printMsg("Hello")
```

> Hello6

In the `update`'s definition, I do not tell it what to do. I just tell that assign the object's `x` property the result of `f(x)`. But what `f(x)` does is not defined anywhere.

However, when I call the `update()` function, I pass on a function value: `i => i + 5`. Does this mean that every time I call `update`, I define the function and keep in mind that this new function should take and return an `Int`?

I also read [How Higher Order functions work in Scala post on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67841946/how-higher-order-function-works-in-scala) and I am not sure whether I got it right:

The function:

```
def higher_order(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int,f:(Int,Int)=>Int):Int=f(f(a,b),c)
```

takes 3 integers and one functional value which furthermore takes two integers and return one integer. The function `f` is not defined anywhere, however, the function `higher_order` is defined as: take 3 integers, take one functional value, return an integer and perform: `f(f(a,b),c)`.
The OP calls this function as: `higher_order(1,2,3,_+_)` and gets the result as 6.

The OP defines `_+_` as the last argument in place of the function value parameter. So, is my thought process of defining the function value upon calling and ensuring that the args and return type matches is valid?

Comment: Why do you say that `f` is not defined anywhere but you don't ask the same for _"plain"_ values like `x`, `msg`, `a`, `b`, `c`? Think about it, that is the point in **Scala** `Functions` are just values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this mean that every time I call update, I define the function

No, not necessarily. The `update` method takes a function as a parameter:

```
def update(f: Int => Int) = x = f(x)
```

When `update` is called, a function must be passed to it. One way is to define a *lambda function* where the function is called:

```
box.update(i => i + 5)
```

This *lambda function* is created by the compiler once and then passed to `update` every time this code is called. Using a *lambda function* avoids the need to name the function and makes the code simpler and cleaner. (In this case it could even be `update(_ + 5)` which is short but easily understood once you get to know Scala)

If you call `update` the same way in another part of the code, a second *lambda function* is created and passed to `update`.

```
box1.update(i => i + 5) // First lambda function instance
box2.update(i => i + 5) // This is a different function instance
```

But the function can also be defined once in advance and passed to `update`:

```
def add5(i: Int) = i + 5

box.update(add5)
```

In this case the definition of `add5` is independent of the call to `update`. And `add5` is a single function that can be used multiple times which, in some cases, may be clearer:

```
box1.udpate(add5)
box2.update(add5)
box3.update(add5)
```

In both cases the type of `f` must be compatible with `Int => Int`. In the case of a lambda function, the compiler knows what type is expected and applies the appropriate types to the arguments if they are not provided. Thus when you pass `i => i + 5` to `Int => Int`, the compiler set the type of `i` to `Int` because that is what `Int => Int` expects.  For the stand-alone `add5` function the type of `i` must be supplied explicitly because the compiler doesn't know how this function  is going to be used.

---

To break down the more complex high-order functions, just remember that functions are types like any other. They can be nested inside each other, used as arguments to other functions, and used to parameterise standard containers like `List` (e.g. `List[Int => Int]`)

Comment: I would also point out that, if the function requires access to other variables in the enclosing scope, then the compiler would be forced to create a new instance every time that call-site is encountered.

For example:
`def updateBy(y: Int) = b.update(_ + y)`